# How can I produce a fractal pattern on the oscilloscope using resistors, capacitors, op amps, MUX's, comparators, and other common circuit components?

Tags: oscilloscope

I found this online and as amazing as it is, I don't have multipliers so I can't build this. This spurred me to find other things that I could design on the oscilloscope using basic components. One idea I had is to make fractals. How can I produce a fractal pattern on the oscilloscope using relatively basic circuit components?

Comment: Fractals (at least Mandelbrot) require a lot of maths and are not at all basic. You might be able to manage a Hilbert curve..

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't happen unless you get the digital involved in some manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you google "Chua's circuit", you will find a simple circuit that will generate chaotic patterns on an oscilloscope using the XY mode. It requires only one op amp and some passive components.  I have built it and it works. Good luck.